# Using LINQ to combine object and nested collection information into a new object

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using LINQ, is it possible to combine properties from both an object and a nested collection of that object into a new object? So for each item in the nested collection, I want to create a new object that has the nested object information coupled with the parent object's info.

Using a sample scenario, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Teachers.Select(Function(item) New TeacherRecord() With
                                 {.TeacherId = item.Id, 
                                  .TeacherName = item.Name, 
                                  .StudentID = ? , 
                                  .StudentName = ?}).ToList()
```

Sample Classes

```
Public Property Teachers as List(of Teacher) 

Public Class Teacher
    Public Property ID as Integer
    Public Property Name as String
    Public Property Room as String
    Public Property Students as List(of Student)
End class

Public Class Student
    Public Property ID as Integer
    Public Property Name as String
End Class

Public Class TeacherRecord
    Public Property TeacherId as Integer
    Public Property TeacherName as String
    Public Property StudentId as Integer
    Public Property StudentName as String
End Class
```

Comment: Use `SelectMany` for that.

Comment: It's just a sample. It's the principal I'm after :P (I know, bad pun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany`, I don't know much about VB but this is how you do it in C#:

```
List<TeacherRecord> records = teachers.SelectMany(t => t.Students, (t, s) =>
                              new TeacherRecord { TeacherId = t.ID, 
                                  TeacherName = t.Name, 
                                  StudentId = s.ID, 
                                  StudentName = s.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for and c# is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to rethink your TeacherRecord relationship to a Teacher Or Student  - now it is unclear, but generally you can combine then for your ViewData and code will look like this:

```
void Main(){
List<Teacher> teacher = new List<Teacher>();
List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
student.Add(new Student{ID=1,Name="Tom"});
student.Add(new Student{ID=2,Name="Jerry"});

teacher.Add(new Teacher{ID=1
                    ,Name="John"
                    ,Room = "Room A"
                    ,Students = student});



var combined = (from t in teacher
        select t).ToList();


    }

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Teacher
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Room { get; set; }
public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherRecord
{
public int TeacherId { get; set; }
public string TeacherName { get; set; }
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

and result will be something like this:

[image]